# Alternatives to dropdown list when possible results are not known

Tags: website-design, search, filter, drop-down-list, overflow

For quite some time I've been looking around the web for alternatives to a dropdown list in assignment of data (i.e., during data capture that will be saved, NOT when searching for some data).

One alternative that is commonly suggested are 'auto-complete text boxes' - but only when at least some of the data is known.

Imagine, however, selection of a city in a specific country. The user might not know what he is specifically looking for, therefore listing all cities identified by zipcode or their name. 
For that scenario, a popup with full search capabilities might be used, however slowing down the process again.

What else comes do your mind? What are you commonly using? Are you aware of any major side which found a great solution for this?

---

*[Update]*

Having found that I failed to properly describe my question (sorry for that), I try to clarify using a screenshot for demonstration purposes.

[image: Screenshot]

Please assume a form for adding new customers, where the customer name and your main contact employee to that new customer is captured.
The employee (assume a big company with thousands of employees) are identified by four attributes:

- gender
- first name
- last name
- branch

In the screenshot above, I displayed them in a dropdown list, but I think it is obvious that this list is not usable anymore. Since employees differ in 4 attributes, I think also an auto-suggestion is not really usable. So what else do you commonly use for that purpose?

Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Do you have any other examples of "when possible results are not known"? I'm still not clear from your question what that means exactly.

Comment: I agree.  Would love to provide some feedback but your question is cloudy and ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is "not known to the user", i.e., he does not know in advance what to select but will find out after some search. For instance, the cities. The user might not know which city he will select, so he first needs to be provided a search functionality as provided by a popup. When he would know, for example, he is looking for something starting with "New ..." an auto-complete text box might be suitable ... when he starts typing "New", he is provided with suggestions. But I talk about situations where the user does NOT know what he is possibly looking for.

Comment: Another example would be: Selection of a person, where the name, the major identification criterion, is not known. The user will only know which person to select after having seen a list of the available ones, e.g., filtered by their nationality, their city, and their gender. I hope that's more understandable now, otherwise please let me know. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: So, is what you're looking after some sort of query UI? How large is the data set, how many fields, …? Does it make sense to show a subset in a table/browser, so the user has an idea of what is there? A filter would then refine the shown results. However, you're needs are still a bit vague…

Comment: @Peter Frings, Yes, I think the wording "query UI" describes it perfectly! I'm talking about scenarious where the dataset is too large to be loaded to the client side in advance (let's assume > 1000), and several fields (>3). I like the idea of showing a 'table/browser' and the possibility to filter it - are you aware of any major side/example, which I might use to get an impression of your thoughts?

Comment: @bonafiz Well, google has something similar: you type in a word, it shows you a list of matches, and on the left side you can fine-tune the search results (type of material, recent items, …) Flickr's search offers something similar as well. The problem will be to have enough (meta-)data to assist the user in finding what he's looking for, if he doesn't know it him himself... Otherwise have a look at data mining applications? (probably a bit over the top…)

Comment: Do you refer to the advanced search of google? I think that might do the job for just searching and selecting something, but I cannot quite imagine how to use that as a dropdown-replacement for assignment on the data capture form. Which data mining applications do you mean for example?

Comment: As edited in main question, posted a demonstration screenshot on http://imgur.com/VWeBV

Comment: @bonifaz No, I'm not referring to the advanced search, but the elements on the left side, where you can restrict the found list to video's, photo's, books, blogs, pages written in english, translated, ... In your case, you could have a list to filter on male/female, different branches, … Still, I'm wondering how on earth does one know you've got the right person?

Comment: Ok I understand, but how would you include that in that assignment form? I think it's different to your google example to that extent that the google page is purely a search form, whereas mine is not. Let's assume the user will recognize which person to select as soon as he is presented a list, but does not know for sure in advance.

Comment: @bonifaz If your users don't know what/whom they're looking for, they need a search facility, right? I often need to forward an article I remember reading on the web of which I forgot the link. So I go to Google, type a few things in I remember from the article, and when I see it in the list I'll probably recognize it and click it. Isn't that something similar to what you need? How do you expect your users to find a single entry in a set of thousands if they don't know what to look for?

Comment: @bonifaz BTW, please use the ‘@user’ reference in your comments to have your answers appear in that person's inbox; that makes it easier to respond.

Comment: @Peter Frings, yes that's right, propably they need a search facility. But how to present to them in the aforementioned example? Clearly, an entire 'search form' can not be included in a data entry form.

Answer (score 6):

How about a dialog with a sortable table with the four parameters as columns, similar to the "TO:" dialog in MS Outlook?

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed displaying that as a popup might be an option. Are you aware of any web application that made proper use of that already?

Comment: @bonifaz Nothing comes to mind right now, sorry.. GMail have something similar when you press "To:", but there's only one column there.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a good compromise can be something like JQuery - Chosen (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/): it simply add a filter keeping the visuals aspects of a normal select box.

Comment: I think this is still too similar to the combo-box described above. These fields only allow you to browse by one pre-defined order (usually alphabetically). Yes, it looks better but I don't think this will give the flexibility required.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do things on my apps that has a similar function is by using a text-field as the input and a `<ul>` below it to contain suggestions based off what the user has typed. Similar to the search engines auto-suggest feature.

Comment: thanks for your thought. However, as described above, I'm mainly focusing on UIs where auto-suggestions is not usable, because the possible results are not known by the user, and several fields of the possible results might be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get the issue with a simple textbox that auto-completes on all four fields? Auto-suggestion should apply seamlessly to all four attributes at the same time.

I use such a textbox in a case where a customer account needs to be selected. Such an account has an id, a full name, a country and an office location and there's about 15000 accounts, way too many for a simple dropdown and you can't require someone to know the id. Typing will quickly match and show filtered results without ever having to leave the keyboard, showing a nicely formatted HTML-dropdown with multiline result items(such as showing country and office on the second row)...

...a bit like a simple Google instant. Because, if you wanted to search by branch and didn't know the name of the person - at least you'd have to know the name of the branch and start typing that?

Also, the query is made to the server async only returning the matches after the first few characters are typed, so there's no need to load 15000 accounts to the browser.

You could have the advanced popup search box as an option when someone is lost or just don't know what to start typing, and leave the seamless typing for normal case efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping the drop-down box, but adding a 'filter' text field to narrow the results down? If you filter the results based on the filter text being anywhere in the list item, rather than just the start, it could work.

So for your drop-down box, the user could at least type 'Chicago' into the filter box to reduce the list to people from that city (or people called Chicago I guess!). Or if they're looking for a specific person but all they can remember is that their last name ended with 'son', then they can type in 'son' and get all of the Jacksons, Johnsons, etc to display.

Honestly, if you have a huge dataset to pick from, and the user has no idea what they're looking for, I can't think of many ways to present it elegantly.